# TimerTask is scheduled for every 15 minutes to refresh the data of app. How can i execute the timertask for once outside the class

Tags: android, timertask

TimerTask is scheduled for every 15 minutes to refresh the data of the app. How can i execute the TimerTask for once outside the class without affecting the scheduled timer task as i have to keep updating the data of the app every 15 minutes. There is a scenario where i need to immediately update the data outside the class.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer();




        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (timer == null) {
                                cancel();
                            }
                            Boolean isInternetPresent = internetCheck.isConnectingToInternet();
                            if(isInternetPresent)
                            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                            else
                                System.out.println("Internet connection not presents ");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 900000);
        }

 public  class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            long s_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            android.util.Log.i("Start  ", " Time value in millisecinds " + s_time);
            String xmlDataOverHttp = PostData();
            long e_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            android.util.Log.i("End  ", " Time value in millisecinds " + e_time);
            Myregistry registry= AppRegistry.getInstance();
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            MyObject example = null;
            try {
                example = serializer.read(MyObject.class, student_xml);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(MyObjectXMl, xmlDataOverHttp);
            editor.apply();
            registry.setObject(example);
            return xmlDataOverHttp;
        }

        
        public String PostData() {
        Boolean s = false;
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        String url = "http://localhost:8080" +"/get_xml_data?id=" + 1;
        System.out.println("url----------" + url);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        String token = readResponse(httpResponse);
        return token;
    }
```

Here MyAsyncTask is scheduled in TimerTask which gets called after every 15 minutes. How can i call this MyAsyncTask outside the class without affecting the scheduled TimerTask. I cnnot make MyAsyncTask  class as static.

Comment: Use a foreground service.

Comment: i am kind of new inandroid.  can u send me some example links

Comment: What you mean by outside the class?

Comment: i can update the data from anypoint in the appp. for example user enters a new data i need to update the data

Comment: A foreground service is something that runs behind the scenes. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: thats why i have a timer taks which updates the data after every 15 minutes but sometime i need to update it immediately

Comment: Just write the common method to update the data and call it from wherever it required.

Comment: i m not able to write it because i need to make static method to get it access outside the class then if i am making a call its affecting the timer task scheduler getting runtime exception

Comment: whenever/where ever you need, you can just use this `new MyAsyncTask().execute();` ex, in an `onClick()` of a button maybe ?

Comment: thats now working in this case new MyAsyncTask().execute() method is not getiing called any other thing i can do with timer object

Comment: you need to make it clear, `is not getiing called` is not enough, update the question add what you have tried, where was that code placed in your project? on a click event? did you get any error logs (exceptions) you need to provide good/useful information so others can help you

Comment: getiing this                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: are you touching the UI views from within `doInbackground()`? i suggest you append your `MyAsyncTask` code to the question

Comment: just updated the question with the code